# Wrapper build errors when attempting to compile code

Tags: c#

Ok so I completely re-wrote the code for this in an attempt to make this simpler. Now it is telling me that "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected. I can only think my spacing is off or i'm missing a bracket, but when i try to add a bracket i get the same error. All I want to do is create simple wrapper for my EXE and its been very frustrating. Please if possible look at my code and tell me what i am doing wrong here. Any help is welcomed...

```
using System.IO;
//using Resources.resx;

namespace EXE_program
{
   public class LaunchEXE
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            string exeName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "EntUpdate_v3.0.exe");
            string argsLin = "";
            int timeoutSeconds = 100;}

            internal static string Run(string exeName, string argsLine, int timeoutSeconds)
            {

                StreamReader outputStream = StreamReader.Null;
                string output = "";
                bool success = false;



                Process newProcess = new Process();
                newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = exeName;
                newProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = argsLine;
                newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                newProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //The command line is supressed to keep the process in the background
                newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                newProcess.Start();


            return "\t" + output; }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any compiler **warnings**? there could be some useful information there

Comment: If this is the only class in (for example) a console application; you are missing main method. I get following error: Error: `Program '[...]\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SPDB\SPDB\obj\x86\Debug\SPDB.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point`

Comment: No that is the bizarre thing none at all besides this:  1>------ Build started: Project: Encryption EXE Wrapper, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>CSC : error CS5001: Program 'c:\Visual Studio Projects\Encryption EXE Wrapper\Encryption EXE Wrapper\obj\Release\Encryption EXE Wrapper.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: See yea Styxxy I was getting that before, but I am not getting that error anymore.

Comment: It means exactly what it says it means.  You need to rename your function to Main.  And you might need to remove the internal keyword also.

Comment: Ah ok Shahzard..I will try this.I was wondering this as well. Thanks. I was using MSDN as a reference, but perhaps there are syntax errors in the code they provided

Comment: When creating a Console Application, there must be a static entry point called Main.